# Showing an element with a common ID, hiding others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a system that, when one element is selected, shows an element of the same ID whilst hiding the previous without hiding all instances of that ID (i.e. it is only hidden if a certain class is present).
The first part (making an element 'active' and setting the ID variable) works fine, but I can't seem to get the secondary element to stop being set using the '.hidden' class.

The code I'm using for this part  is

```
function showSelect() {
    select = $(".active").attr('id');
        $(".items").addClass("hidden");
        $("#"+select).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

I've tried using $(select).remove... on the fourth line, as well as what is currently present, but to no avail. 
The rest of the code can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/ActualRealJamz/2JZA6/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and JSHint reports no syntax error of any kind - so in that there must be an error to my method.
If this happens to be of any use, Chrome reports an 'Unexpected identifier' on the line `$(".items").addClass("hidden");`.

Any help in this matter is most appreciated.

Comment: IDs are required to be unique, you can't have elements with the same ID.

Comment: you can do it with items with the same class. As Barmar said, id's are required to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that, this is something of which I was not aware. This behaviour probably explains why I've had quite a few issues in the past where IDs have been involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar pointed out in the comments, that fundamentally cannot work because you cannot have the same `id` on more than one element. If you do, the document is invalid and the browser is free to ignore the `id` values. (In practice, they typically act as though only the first element in the document with a given `id` value has that `id`, ignoring subsequent ones.)

You seem to be using the class `items` on the relevant elements, so it's straight-forward to do what you're looking to do. Assuming `showSelect` is attached to the relevant elements as a `click` handler, within `showSelect`, `this` will be the specific element that was clicked. So:

```
// Hooking it up
$(".items").click(showSelect);

// The function
function showSelect() {
    $(".items").not(this).addClass("hidden");
    $(this).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

No `id`s required at all.

Comment: In this case I can't use (this) as `items` are all set to be hidden by default. Although I could switch out the IDs for classes without much issue. However, as you previously stated `$("#"+select)` would work as intended, so surely `$("."+select)` would behave in precisely the same way.

In this case, how would I get that to simply output as a class? Or, if preferable (in terms of good practice, etc.) save the variable with the `.` prefix?,

Comment: You can assign `var allItems = $(".items");`

Comment: @user2957638: Actually, I misread that line. `select = $(".active").attr("id");` will give you the `id` value of the *first* element with the class `active` (or `undefined` if there are none). I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to hide all `.items` elements except ones that are `.active`, then: `$(".items").not(".active").addClass("hidden"); $(".items.active").removeClass("hidden");`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I might not have been very clear. What I mean was to change `#1` to `.1` and so on and so forth. What I wanted to do was to save the variable as so that I could do `$(select).removeClass("hidden")`  where `select` would be `.1/2/3/...`
This doesn't actually matter, though. My idea of this came out of a mistake. My previous method was much easier :P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, an honest mistake. I was using two functions, where the first would highlight and elements by marking it as '.active'. As '.active' would only be available when an element was selected it would make logical sense to use that to find which of the `.items` elements to remove the `.hidden` label from.